# "pmset" values changed after system update and started battery drain

Tags: macos, battery, bluetooth, sleep-wake

I had Monterey 12.5 (21G72) and `pmset -g` output used to be like this:

```
System-wide power settings:
DestroyFVKeyOnStandby 0
Currently in use:
standby 1
standbydelaylow 10800
halfdim 1
hibernatefile /var/vm/sleepimage
proximitywake 0
powernap 0
gpuswitch 2
acwake 0
disksleep 10
standbydelayhigh 86400
sleep 1
hibernatemode 3
ttyskeepawake 1
displaysleep 2
tcpkeepalive 1
highstandbythreshold 50
lowpowermode 0
lidwake 1
```

But after updating to Monterey 12.5.1 (21G83) they changed:

```
System-wide power settings:
DestroyFVKeyOnStandby 0
Currently in use:
lidwake 1
lowpowermode 0
standbydelayhigh 86400
proximitywake 1
standby 1
standbydelaylow 10800
ttyskeepawake 1
highstandbythreshold 50
powernap 1
gpuswitch 2
hibernatefile /var/vm/sleepimage
hibernatemode 3
displaysleep 8
womp 1
networkoversleep 0
sleep 0
tcpkeepalive 1
halfdim 1
acwake 0
disksleep 10
```

The battery in sleep mode (when external power is not plugged in) started to drain dramatically: I open the lid and it just show red low battery sign.

The command output is full of bluetooth and TCP events where I can trace the drain (though I turned bluetooth off long ago).

```
 pmset -g log | grep -e "Wake from" -e "DarkWake" -e "due to"
```

```
2022-09-06 02:09:17 +0300 DarkWake              DarkWake from Standby [CDN] : due to EC.Bluetooth/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:10%) 12 secs   
2022-09-06 02:09:29 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:9%) 25 secs   
2022-09-06 02:09:54 +0300 DarkWake              DarkWake from Standby [CDN] : due to EC.Bluetooth/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:9%) 14 secs   
2022-09-06 02:10:08 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:10%) 22 secs   
2022-09-06 02:10:30 +0300 DarkWake              DarkWake from Standby [CDN] : due to EC.Bluetooth/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:10%) 15 secs   
2022-09-06 02:10:45 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:10%) 23 secs   
2022-09-06 02:11:08 +0300 DarkWake              DarkWake from Standby [CDN] : due to EC.Bluetooth/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:10%) 9 secs    
2022-09-06 02:11:17 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:9%) 29 secs   
2022-09-06 02:11:46 +0300 DarkWake              DarkWake from Standby [CDN] : due to EC.Bluetooth/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:9%) 14 secs   
2022-09-06 02:12:00 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:9%) 25 secs   
2022-09-06 02:12:25 +0300 DarkWake              DarkWake from Standby [CDN] : due to EC.Bluetooth/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:9%) 13 secs   
2022-09-06 02:12:38 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:9%) 23 secs   
2022-09-06 02:13:01 +0300 DarkWake              DarkWake from Standby [CDN] : due to EC.Bluetooth/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:9%) 27 secs   
2022-09-06 02:13:28 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:9%) 25 secs   
2022-09-06 02:13:53 +0300 DarkWake              DarkWake from Standby [CDN] : due to EC.Bluetooth/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:9%) 10 secs   
2022-09-06 02:14:03 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:8%) 24 secs   
2022-09-06 02:14:27 +0300 DarkWake              DarkWake from Standby [CDN] : due to EC.Bluetooth/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:8%) 14 secs   
2022-09-06 02:14:41 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:9%) 31 secs   
2022-09-06 02:15:12 +0300 DarkWake              DarkWake from Standby [CDN] : due to EC.Bluetooth/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:9%) 10 secs   
2022-09-06 02:15:22 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:8%) 23 secs   
2022-09-06 02:15:45 +0300 DarkWake              DarkWake from Standby [CDN] : due to EC.Bluetooth/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:8%) 14 secs
```

```
2022-09-09 02:33:24 +0300 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDN] : due to EC.Bluetooth/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:90%) 7 secs    
2022-09-09 02:33:31 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:90%) 3 secs    
2022-09-09 02:33:34 +0300 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDN] : due to EC.Bluetooth/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:90%) 7 secs    
2022-09-09 02:33:41 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:90%) 3 secs    
2022-09-09 02:33:44 +0300 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDN] : due to EC.Bluetooth/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:90%) 7 secs    
2022-09-09 02:33:51 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:90%) 28 secs   
2022-09-09 02:34:19 +0300 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDN] : due to EC.Bluetooth/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:90%) 7 secs    
2022-09-09 02:34:26 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:90%) 18 secs   
2022-09-09 02:34:44 +0300 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDN] : due to EC.Bluetooth/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:90%) 0 secs    
2022-09-09 02:34:44 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:90%) 3 secs    
2022-09-09 02:34:47 +0300 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDN] : due to EC.Bluetooth/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:90%) 7 secs    
2022-09-09 02:34:54 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:89%) 11 secs   
2022-09-09 02:35:05 +0300 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDN] : due to EC.Bluetooth/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:89%) 7 secs    
2022-09-09 02:35:12 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:89%) 4 secs    
2022-09-09 02:35:16 +0300 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDN] : due to EC.Bluetooth/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:89%) 7 secs    
2022-09-09 02:35:23 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:89%) 3 secs    
2022-09-09 02:35:26 +0300 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDN] : due to EC.Bluetooth/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:89%) 7 secs    
2022-09-09 02:35:33 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:89%) 3 secs    
2022-09-09 02:35:36 +0300 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDN] : due to EC.Bluetooth/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:89%) 7 secs    
2022-09-09 02:35:43 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:89%) 4 secs    
2022-09-09 02:35:47 +0300 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDN] : due to EC.Bluetooth/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:89%) 7 secs    
2022-09-09 02:35:54 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:89%) 3 secs    
2022-09-09 02:35:57 +0300 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDN] : due to EC.Bluetooth/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:89%) 7 secs    
2022-09-09 02:36:04 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:89%) 3 secs    
2022-09-09 02:36:07 +0300 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDN] : due to EC.Bluetooth/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:89%) 7 secs    
2022-09-09 02:36:14 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:89%) 3 secs    
2022-09-09 02:36:17 +0300 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDN] : due to EC.Bluetooth/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:89%) 7 secs    
2022-09-09 02:36:24 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:89%) 4 secs    
2022-09-09 02:36:28 +0300 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDN] : due to EC.Bluetooth/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:89%) 7 secs    
2022-09-09 02:36:35 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:89%) 3 secs    
2022-09-09 02:36:38 +0300 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDN] : due to EC.Bluetooth/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:89%) 7 secs    
2022-09-09 02:36:45 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:89%) 3 secs    
2022-09-09 02:36:48 +0300 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDN] : due to EC.Bluetooth/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:89%) 7 secs    
2022-09-09 02:36:55 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:89%) 3 secs    
2022-09-09 02:36:58 +0300 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDN] : due to EC.Bluetooth/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:89%) 7 secs    
2022-09-09 02:37:05 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:89%) 4 secs    
2022-09-09 02:37:09 +0300 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDN] : due to EC.Bluetooth/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:89%) 6 secs    
2022-09-09 02:37:15 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:89%) 4 secs    
2022-09-09 02:37:19 +0300 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDN] : due to EC.Bluetooth/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:89%) 7 secs    
2022-09-09 02:37:26 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:89%) 3 secs    
2022-09-09 02:37:29 +0300 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDN] : due to EC.Bluetooth/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:89%) 7 secs    
2022-09-09 02:37:36 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:89%) 11 secs   
2022-09-09 02:37:47 +0300 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDN] : due to EC.Bluetooth/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:89%) 7 secs    
2022-09-09 02:37:54 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:89%) 4 secs    
2022-09-09 02:37:58 +0300 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDN] : due to EC.Bluetooth/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:89%) 7 secs    
2022-09-09 02:38:05 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:89%) 3 secs    
2022-09-09 02:38:08 +0300 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDN] : due to EC.Bluetooth/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:89%) 12 secs   
2022-09-09 02:38:20 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:89%) 4 secs    
2022-09-09 02:38:24 +0300 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDN] : due to EC.Bluetooth/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:89%) 7 secs    
2022-09-09 02:38:31 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:88%) 3 secs    
2022-09-09 02:38:34 +0300 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDN] : due to EC.Bluetooth/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:88%) 7 secs
```

Updating to 12.6 (21G115) and resetting SMC did not solve the problem.

Does anyone has any clues to help sort this problem out and stop the drain?

Comment: I surmise (but don't know) that your bluetooth wakes are due to the `proximitywake` changes. I am not convinced that your bluetooth is off, nor is it desirable for it to be off (in most cases).

Answer (score 1):

There don't seem to be major changes in your list, though two that standout to me are `proximitywake` and `powernap`. On my 2016 MacBook the settings did not change for any of the Monterey updates.

Some of the settings can be changed in System Preferences > Battery. That includes PowerNap and Display Sleep.

Where settings can't be changed via System Preferences, they can be changed with the `pmset` command, for example:

`sudo pmset -b proximitywake 0`

That should allow you to set things back how to what they were before.

People have differing views on good values for the settings and that can vary on different Mac models. I will venture some comments on your settings which could lead to better battery life whilst sleeping:

1. I prefer smaller values for the two `standbydelays` which are in seconds. This is to speed up the transition into deeper sleep modes.
2. A non-zero value for `tcpkeepalive` means that the Mac keeps on waking for network traffic. The same applies to `womp` though I don't have that on my MacBook.

For comparison, with my underpowered 2016 MacBook I have these values:

```
 lidwake              1
 autopoweroff         1
 standbydelayhigh     7200
 autopoweroffdelay    14400
 standbydelaylow      7200
 standby              1
 proximitywake        0
 ttyskeepawake        1
 hibernatemode        3
 powernap             0
 gpuswitch            2
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 highstandbythreshold 50
 displaysleep         4
 sleep                1
 acwake               0
 halfdim              1
 tcpkeepalive         0
 disksleep            1
```

My MacBook sleeps happily with only 1 or 2 percent drop in battery level next day. If I were to change anything it would be to reduce the delays to 1 hour (3600 seconds).

Comment: Not sure why no one has up voted your answer, so have a cookie on me! :)